# Is it worth it using the built-in Django admin for a decent sized project?

Tags: django, django-admin

I haven't been using Django too long, but I'm about to start a pretty hefty-sized project. I'm always nervous using fairly new frameworks (new to me) on large projects because I've been burned before. However, I'm pretty confident in Django...this will finally be the project that makes me leap from my home-grown PHP framework to a popular Python framework. (yay!)

Anyway, my question is whether or not the built-in Django admin is robust enough to use for a fully-fledged customer-facing interface (the clients will be using it themselves, not me). I see that it's pretty customizable, but I'm wondering if extensible enough to handle various non-standard cases. I don't have any concrete examples yet since I haven't started yet.

Has anyone used the Django admin for some pretty customized interfaces that non-programmer users use? Was it worth it? Would you rather have just created a home-grown admin interface specifically for the site?

Just to clarify, the users would be completely non-techy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to use the django admin for all users, to let them update the site.
If this is true, I think you may be using it in a different way from what was its main purpose, as you can get from the [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06/) (emphasis is mine):

> For a certain class of Web sites, an
>   admin interface is an essential part
>   of the infrastructure. This is a
>   Web-based interface, *limited to
>   trusted site administrators*, that
>   enables the adding, editing and
>   deletion of site content.

If your users need to update content (like, let's say, adding a new article) then it may be OK.
But if you want to use it for any site interaction, then I think the user experience will not be as good.

I think a very nice example of how the admin can be used, and when it should not be used is in [ReviewBoard](http://www.review-board.org/): there, most of user actions are handled directly by the site, and only the configuration and management are then handled using the admin.

In the end, it is a matter of **usability**. If you think that it is OK for your application to have a different section to manage addition to the site, then Django's admin site may be a real time saver. In all other cases, maybe it is better to invest some time more.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head with that quote from the Django book. I guess I was thinking about morphing the admin into something it's not really designed to do. That would probably lead to trouble down the road.

Answer (score 3):

My company has built a CMS on top of Django that handles numerous tasks (flat pages, blogs, members-only sections, importing and parsing data from external sites like youtube and flickr, mailing lists, albums songs and lyrics for artists, etc.) and so far we're still using the built-in admin. We have several very non-technical clients using it regularly.

You can go pretty far in customizing it with the admin.py files when you really get into it. The only things we've added are tinyMCE and Filebrowser to make those aspects easier for the end users.

I will say that we are working on a gallery module that *is* going to need a custom admin, though. Otherwise I've been pretty happy and impressed with how flexible and powerful Django's admin can be. And it's as user-friendly as you can think to make it.

Comment: Do you think you'll have any trouble making a customized admin piece that at least looks like the rest of the admin?

Comment: Making it look like the rest, no. Just letting the admin stylesheet do its job and making sure to add the appropriate classes should take care of that. We're more concerned with how to design the interface for some of the more complicated pieces like reordering and thumbnailing.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.  The admin will let you customize quite a bit, with different groups of users having access to different tables, and if you give them access to different admin interfaces, you can even give them different sets of columns available on the tables.  However, the admin isn't really set up to let you restrict users' row level access based on their authorization level.  Once you've let them into a table, they can make changes to any object available to them.

You can customize widgets however you like by subclassing widget types (though the built-in filter_horizontal and raw_id_admin are indispensable and make this task simple for certain data types!)

So I guess it depends on what you mean by customers.  If you mean the people who hired you to write the website (I think I'd call them clients rather than customers), then there's a good chance the admin will suit you just fine.  If you mean the end users of a website, I would stick with hand-crafted django forms.

Comment: I guess technically the "customers" would be both clients and customers...meaning the people that hired me might manage users, but the users themselves would be very non-technical and only be able to manage certain parts.

Comment: I just tried the filter_horizontal on my practice site...very nice! Good tip!

Answer (score 2):

In general I view the Django admin as an interface to performing the tedious tasks of insert delete and editing. So, I'm not afraid of customizing it to a large extent (even if this means subclassing internal Django objects and passing them back to the admin interface at runtime), but be aware it will require you to read Django source (which fortunately isn't very hard to do).

So for me, the discriminator of using it or not is "insert, delete, update" of concepts that map very well to the database tables, not amount of user technical knowledge, amount I trust the users, or project size.

Comment: That's a very good way of thinking about it. Once I design how the site is going to work, I'll have to see if it fits that model.